# How to use cgi form input as variable in call to system command in Python script?

Tags: python, bash, shell, ubuntu, cgi

Say I have a web page like this on an Ubuntu 12.04 web server running apache:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  http-equiv="content-type">
  <title>Name Input</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <form action="./test.py" method="post"> 
      <p> Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""/></p> 
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to use the value of `name` as input to a shell script which is called by a Python CGI script like this.

test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import commands, cgi, cgitb
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
name = form.getvalue('name') 
result = commands.getoutput("/usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.sh name")
contents = pageTemplate.format(**locals())
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print contents
```

**In the example code above, how should `name` be passed to test.sh?**

For completeness, say that pageTemplate looks like this:

```
pageTemplate = '''<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  http-equiv="content-type">
  <title>Name Output</title>
</head>
  <body>
    {result}
  </body>
</html>
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass it into the command:

```
result = commands.getoutput("/usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.sh %s" % name)
```